# How to bootstrap flink operator with multiple states

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The new state process API works great to bootstrap a state object in an operator. However, I could not find any example of how to bootstrap multiple states from a single operator. Looking at the code it appears to be not supported. Wonder if anyone has suggestion on how to solve this problem. My use case is that I have implemented a customized join operator that contains left and right state. I need to bootstrap both state with data from hive tables.

Comment: The KeyedStateBootstrapFunction interface does seem like allow me to write multiple states(I have not tried yet). But it only takes one type of element which requires me to encode multiple state information in one stream for bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I can see would be to construct a single DataSet holding a type that can hold all the data, such as a Tuple or a Map (for each key), and then use that single compound DataSet to bootstrap all of the states.

Comment: This does not work because currently for example, Savepoint
    .load(bEnv, new MemoryStateBackend(), oldPath)
    .withOperator("uid", transformation)
    .write(newPath);
The withOperator can only have one transformation for each operator,

Comment: I've rewritten my answer, proposing an alternative that I believe will work.

Comment: This is also what I have been working on now. I will report back how it works. It is not user friendly and a hacky solution. I wonder if flink state process api can be changed to allow multiple bootstrap transforms per operator?

Comment: Just want to followup on this. We end up implement with above proposal and it works. thanks.